# Ruby - how can I set the first element of a 2 dimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
$ irb
2.0.0-p247 :001 > my_array=[['','',''],['','',''],['','','']]
 => [["", "", ""], ["", "", ""], ["", "", ""]] 

2.0.0-p247 :003 > my_array[[0][0]]='o' 
 => "o" 

2.0.0-p247 :004 > my_array
 => ["o", ["", "", ""], ["", "", ""]] 
2.0.0-p247 :005 >
```

But I wanted to get:

```
 => ["o","",""] ["", "", ""], ["", "", ""]]
```

and I don't just want to do `my_array[[0][0]]=['o' ,'','']`

Comment: `my_array[0][0] = 'o'`

Comment: The value of `[0][0]` is `0` (it's the first element of the array whose only element is `0`). So `my_array[[0][0]]` is the same as `my_array[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
my_array[0][0] = 'o'
```

About your mistake, calling `array[[0][0]]` is the same as `array[0]`.
`[0]` creates an array containing `0`, then by doing `[0][0]` (same as `[0].[](0)` ) you are calling the first element of the array [0] which returns `0`.